# Connection refusing after updating directory with git

Tags: git

I get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error when I try to access an index.html file stored on a server through my browser. I recently added git to the directory that holds that file. I checked the permissions on it and they're -rwxr-xr-x

Why is the connection refusing?

Comment: "Connection refused" and "permission denied" are completely different things. Your web server configuration prevents it from accepting connections from your IP. It could be web server config itself or firewall.

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't admin the server. For what reasons would a server refuse? I have been SSHing a lot into the server to edit files.  Could that be an issue? That I've connected too many times and now it refuses public requests? Or does it have anything to do with the git integration? I'm not sure, I'm unfamiliar with the topic.

Comment: It is possible to automatically ban someone who uses too much of bandwidth, yes. But no one here is able to answer if it is done on your server. If you don't have access to server configuration, ask someone who does.